# Проблема с загрузкой Windows 7

Tags: windows

Извините, просто всё перепробовал, нигде не мог найти помощь. В общем, вот моя проблема. Друг получил себе winlock, смог его удалить, а сам файл этот передал мне для изучения. К тому моменту у меня было 2 операционных системы: Windows 7 на диске C: (логич.) и Ubuntu на диске K: (логич., часть систем. диска D:). На диске D: никаких систем не было.

Чтобы протестировать winlock, я установил на D: ОС Windows Vista. Меня предупредили при выборе диска, что всё, что связано с предыдущей ОС, будет перемещено в Windows.old. Установка прошла успешно, winlock работает, но при перезагрузке не остаётся (отключается). Потом я заметил, что у меня перестала загружаться Windows 7: когда я нажимаю Enter в меню выбора ОС для загрузки, появляется чёрный экран и через пару секунд компьютер загружается снова. Windows Vista при этом загружается как обычно, Ubuntu - тоже. Папку Windows (там где Vista) я просто удалил, также переименовал ntldr и BOOT (папку) (той же ОС).

Однако никакого результата это не дало. Даже если я нажимаю F8 (Выбор безоп. режима), когда Win 7 просто выделена, происходит то же самое - чёрный экран и перезагрузка. Посоветуйте хоть что-нибудь, например, как boot.ini отредактировать, или какие файлы на C: переместить, лишь бы Windows 7 загружалась, как раньше. Переустановка не подходит - у меня нет диска и к той системе были привязаны очень многие программы, которые проблемно переустановить (или вообще невозможно). Могу сделать нужные скриншоты, отредактировать что надо, скачать нужные файлы. Описал всё подробно.

P.S. Однажды полетела Windows Vista. При попытке её загрузки выдавалось сообщение (системным шрифтом), что не удалось её загрузить и варианты для выбора. P.S. P.S. Данный winlock не изменяет никаких системных файлов и т.п, лишь должен прописывать себя в автозагрузке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кто ж на рабочей системе вирусы изучает?Оо В виртуалке надо было. Отладчиком...
Ну да уж поздно.

Первый вариант: Попробуйте скачать какой-нибудь live-cd с вин7 (но не обязательно его) и оттуда запустить fixboot для Win 7.

Второй вариант: качаете Win 7, записываете, загружаетесь с диска. Там будет возможность выбрать опцию "Восстановление системы", чем и воспользоваться. (Там есть такая штука: Восстановление запуска).

Вариант три: с помощью чего-нибудь (Live-cd, другой комп и т.д.) копируете загрузочные файлы в корень из заведомо рабочей винды. Не знаю точно, поможет или нет, но мало ли.

Возможно, есть иные варианты, но все требуют какую-либо рабочую систему, пусть и не на этом диске =3

Comment: Оба ответа хорошие, но ваш мне дал больше идей к действию, поэтому принимаю ваш. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Сами себе злобный бука - нужно пользоваться средствами виртуализации для таких целей. Краткий перечень - virtualbox, vmware, ms virtualbox, xen (для linux) и пр.

В данной ситуации очень похоже, что Vista затерла загрузчик Windows Seven. Для восстановления нужно проделать операции аналогичные fixboot/fixmbr инструкциям Recovery Console. Ну, и возможно переписать системные файлы в корне c:

Еще могу посоветовать воспользоваться восстановлением ОСи с дистрибутивного диска. В принципе, не обязательно иметь диск от установленной системы - легко может подойти аналогичный (с учетом возможности необходимости той же самой версии - OEM vs Rtl, поставки - Home vs Home Premium vs Ultimate vs etc.). Оригинальные дистрибутивы можно скачать на многих сайтах. Это даже на самом деле вероятно не нелегально. Т.к. дистрибутив и установленная копия - разные вещи.

Comment: Если честно, у меня та проблемная семёрка и есть нелегальная))) Ну да ничего страшного, у меня все проги либо бесплатные, либо пиратские. И работают! Так что вопрос легальности мне не важен.

Answer (score 1):

Всё получилось. Из той самой папки Windows.old, о которой меня предупреждали при установке Win Vista, я переместил все файлы с заменой в корень D: (т.е. куда устанавливал винду для запуска winlock'а). Там была и папка Boot, и прочие файлы, запускаемые при загрузке винды (AUTOEXEC.BAT, etc.). После этого загрузился, как ни в чём ни бывало. Ntldr отображал всё, как раньше. И загрузка шла, как обычно.